# AddictedCS SoundFingerprinting FFmpeg.AutoGen System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

How can I troubleshoot below issue? Seems to be a class override of FFmpeg.

I am attempting to use AddictedCS SoundFingerprinting (https://github.com/AddictedCS/soundfingerprinting).
https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen

After downloading the packages with nuget, I downloaded & compiled from source to debug:

For some reason FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions keep crashing.
Visual Studio 2022, project set to X64

**The exception:**

FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions
Code line 2906:

***public static AVFormatContext* avformat_alloc_context() => vectors.avformat_alloc_context();***

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  Source=FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions
  StackTrace:
   at FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions.ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context() in C:\FFmpeg.AutoGen-master\FFmpeg.AutoGen.Abstractions\generated\ffmpeg.functions.facade.g.cs:line 2906
```

**ffmpeg.exe as recommended on the correct location**

`C:\fingerPrint\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\x64\Debug\FFmpeg\bin\x64>ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)`

**Sourcecode**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SoundFingerprinting;
using SoundFingerprinting.Builder;
using SoundFingerprinting.Emy;
using FFmpeg.AutoGen.Bindings.DynamicallyLoaded;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private readonly IFingerprintCommandBuilder fingerprintCommandBuilder = new FingerprintCommandBuilder();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var current = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            var probe = Path.Combine("FFmpeg", "bin", Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86");
            var ffmpegBinaryPath = Path.Combine(current, probe);
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg binaries found in: {ffmpegBinaryPath}");
            DynamicallyLoadedBindings.LibrariesPath = ffmpegBinaryPath;
  
            var audioService = new FFmpegAudioService();
            var hashedFingerprints = await FingerprintCommandBuilder.Instance
                                             .BuildFingerprintCommand()
                                             .From("c:\\temp\\chopin_short2.wav")
                                             .UsingServices(audioService)
                                             .Hash();
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I need to look next? Doesn't this work with a console C# project?

Answer (score 0):

added "DynamicallyLoadedBindings.Initialize();" now it works.
Going to reset & restart everything.

```
>   var current = Environment.CurrentDirectory;   var probe =
> Path.Combine("FFmpeg", "bin", Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" :
> "x86");   var ffmpegBinaryPath = Path.Combine(current, probe);  
> Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);  
> Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg binaries found in: {ffmpegBinaryPath}");  
> DynamicallyLoadedBindings.LibrariesPath = ffmpegBinaryPath;  
> DynamicallyLoadedBindings.Initialize();
> 
>   Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg version info:
> {ffmpeg.av_version_info()}"); var audioService = new
> FFmpegAudioService(); var hashedFingerprints = await
> FingerprintCommandBuilder.Instance
>                                  .BuildFingerprintCommand()
>                                  .From("c:\\temp\\chopin_short.wav")
>                                  .UsingServices(audioService)
>                                  .Hash(); Console.WriteLine(hashedFingerprints.ToString());
```